# How to migrate Jboss7.1 application migrate to Tomcat 7.0.54?

Tags: jsf-2, migration, tomcat7, richfaces, jboss7.x

My application is currently using Jboss 7.1 eap server and used JSF and Richfaces as front end and normal bean class as back end with hibernate.

My problem is How to migrate the complete Jboss-7.1 application to Tomcat-7.0.45?
Thank you.

Comment: How is the application packaged? WAR?

Comment: Can you provide details on what have you tried so far and specific issues/errors you are encountering? It would help the community to provide on point answers as well as higher the chances of the question being answered.